# Independence is conversed under $\sigma$-spanning

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega,F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $A$ and $(B_i)_{i\in I}$ be elements of $F$ such that $A$ and $B_i$ is independent for all $i\in I$.

Is it true that $A$ and $\sigma((B_i)_{i\in I})$ is independent (when $I$ is countable, uncountable)?

How can I prove this for a general case?

Comment: Do you mean "conserved," by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Independence is not conserved even when $I$ has two elements. Toss a fair coin twice. Let $A$ be the event that exactly one toss lands heads, let $B_1$ be the event that the first toss lands heads, and $B_2$ be the event that the second toss lands heads. You can check that
$$P(A\cap B_i) = \frac14=P(A)P(B_i)$$
for $i=1,2$. But the event $A$ is not independent of the event $B_1\cap B_2$, since
$$P(A)P(B_1\cap B_2) = \frac 12 \cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12$$
(since $B_1$ and $B_2$ are independent) while the event $A\cap B_1\cap B_2$ is empty. (This is an example of three events that are pairwise independent, but not mutually independent.)